# /bin/bash accidentally moved to another location

Tags: virtual-machine, data-recovery, azure

I have an Azure VM and while I was moving some files from my present working directory with the command `mv`, I accidentally missed the `.` in front of my source and instead wrote

```
mv /* /destination/path
```

This moved some files from `/` (including `/bin` directory) to the destination.

I am locked out of my VM now as I cannot SSH into a Bash terminal there because the terminal doesn't exist in `/bin/bash` (an absolute blunder from my side).

I am here to understand if there's any way to regain access to this VM. I do not have any other shell installed.

Comment: probably not directly. is there a rescue system?

Comment: not really, but I understand that I can create one right now? I'm not sure if azure allows that and a resource to correctly do it would be of huge help!

Comment: @AmitSharma have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/966214/azure-linux-vm-rescue) - it may help.

Comment: Does Azure provide "console" access to the VM (i.e. like Hyper-V does)? If you're able to see the boot menu, it would be easy to recover from there.

Comment: If the SSH server still works *and* [if it uses `internal-sftp` for SFTP](https://superuser.com/a/1585236/432690), *and* if you are allowed to `sftp` to the root account, then probably you can copy `/destination/path/bash` to `/bin` (even if it requires pulling the file to the local machine and putting it back). Do not try to fix everything this way because of file permissions; fix it to the point when you can `ssh`, then `ssh` to an interactive shell and `mv` things properly (invoking `/destination/path/mv` if needed; or copy `mv` like you did copy `bash`).

Comment: If the SSH still works, you can just try to create symlink in `/` to `bin`, like so: `ssh root@hostname "/destination/path/bin/ln -s -t/ /destination/path/bin"`